# Ruby on Rails database and application design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, architecture, rails-postgresql

We have to create rather large Ruby on Rails application based on large database. This database is updated daily, each table has about 500 000 records (or more) and this number will grow over time. We will also have to provide proper versioning of all data along with referential integrity. It must be possible for user to move from version to version, which are kind of "snapshots" of main database at different points of time. In addition some portions of data need to be served to other external applications with and API.

Considering large amounts of data we thought of splitting database into pieces:

1. State of the data at present time
2. Versioned attributes of each table
3. Snapshots of the first database at specific, historical points in time

Each of those would have it's own application, creating a service with API to interact with the data. It's needed as we don't want to create multiple applications connecting to multiple databases directly.

The question is: is this the proper approach? If not, what would you suggest?

We've never had any experience with project of this magnitude and we're trying to find the best possible solution. We don't know if this kind of data separation has any sense. If so, how to provide proper communication of different applications with individual services and between services themselves, as this will be also required.

Comment: wow, have fun with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the amount of data in the tables should not be your first concern.  In PostgreSQL you have a very large number of options to optimize queries against large tables.  The larger question has to do with what exactly you are querying, when, and why.  Your query loads are always larger concerns than the amount of data.  It's one thing to have ten years of financial data amounting to 4M rows.  It's something different to have to aggregate those ten years of data to determine what the balance of the checking account is.

In general it sounds to me like you are trying to create a system that will rely on such aggregates.  In that case I recommend the following approach, which I call log-aggregate-snapshot.  In this, you have essentially three complementary models which work together to provide up-to-date well-performing solution.  However the restrictions on this are important to recognize and understand.

1. Event model.  This is append-only, with no updates.  In this model inserts occur, and updates to some metadata used for some queries only as absolutely needed.  For a financial application this would be the tables representing the journal entries and lines.
2. The aggregate closing model.  This is append-only (though deletes are allowed for purposes of re-opening periods).  This provides roll-forward information for specific purposes.  Once a closing entry is in, no entries can be made for a closed period.  In a financial application, this would represent closing balances.  New balances can be calculated by starting at an aggregation point and rolling forward.  You can also use partial indexes to make it easier to pull just the data you need.
3. Auxiliary data model.  This consists of smaller tables which do allow updates, inserts, and deletes provided that integrity to the other models is not impinged.  In a financial application this might be things like customer or vendor data, employee data, and the like.